# Retrieve Freeze Frame in SWC

Tags: autosar

How can I retrieve/get a freeze frame(The whole freeze frame itself, not just data) in the SWC?

I have *Event ID* and *DemDTC* for the reference. The SWS confuses me.

**[UPDATE]**

I am writing acceptance test for Diagnostic Services, for reference, the test scenario code is **[ATS_DIAG_00247]**.

In the configuration part, it says that:

**A Dem event E06 with DemDTC = 0x666666 must be configured with the following 
properties:**

- DemDebounceMonitorInternal
- FreezeFrame contains variable FreezeFrameCounter (uint32)
- DemEnvironmentDataCapture = DEM_CAPTURE_SYNCHRONOUS_TO_REPORTING
- DemAgingAllowed = FALSE
- No DemEventFailureCycleCounterThreshold defined

It also says:

> The SWC provides the FreezeFrame data through a DID port to the DEM. The 
>   SWC’s variable FreezeFrameCounter is incremented by 1 (with wrap-around at 
>   maximum value)during each periodic invocation of the SWC’s main runnable 
>   (periodicity << 1 sec). The initial value of the FreezeFrameCounter is arbitrary.

### The summary of the test scenario is this

> Memorize the current FreezeFrameCounter value and pre-store a FreezeFrame. 
>   After 2 seconds, report a failed event.
>   Then, check that the event is failed and that the associated FreezeFrame contains 
>   the FreezeFrameCounter with the memorized value.

So here are my assumptions:

- there will be a configured Freeze Frame for a particular *DTC*
- the configured freeze frame has a *member* called **FreezeFrameCounter** which is of the type `uint32` (so I assume that Freeze Frame is a struct)
- I will retrieve the *FreezeFrameCounter* member of the configured *Freeze Frame* and save it into a temporary variable. (how can I retrieve a freeze frame? Or how would I be able to have a reference to that freeze frame?)

I'm really sorry, I'm not an expert in autosar. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, this is hard to decipher. Do you want to read the freeze frame into a software-component or do you want to read the freeze frame out of one specific software-component? None of that would make much sense...

Comment: Hi @UweHonekamp, sorry. I've updated the question, thank you very much!

Comment: The freeze frame is not a structure, but a byte array into which the counter is cast. The buffer into which the freeze frame is put is administrated by the Dem. The freeze frame can be obtained as a response telegram to a request of diagnostic service GetDataByIdentifier submitted by the diagnostic tester.

Comment: hi @UweHonekamp, sorry for the very late reply. I'm trying to retrieve the FreezeFrame from the SWC PCO; in my case, I'm using C and directly including the Autosar libraries. Is there a way to know which part of the byte array is the FreezeFrameCounter? In C, will it still be a byte array or a struct? Thank you!

Comment: You canget this information from the EcuC configuration

Comment: is it the *DemFreezeFrameRecordClass*?

Comment: sorry, there's no other resources I have to learn this.